# Negative hours value in DateInterval::format()

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

i need to convert number of seconds to date, and then show time difference as days, hours and seconds.

But for some reason after some number of days, in last hour before next full day I get negative hours value. Right now this problem occures if date is greater then 38 days (it's before 1st November). Maybe tomorrow this value will be different, I'm not sure.

Code:

```
$s = 84600; // 23.5 h in seconds
$s += (60*60*24)*38; // add 38 days in seconds
$d = (new \DateTime())->modify("-".$s."seconds");
echo (new \DateTime())->diff($d)->format("%a days %h:%I");
// shows: 38 days -1:30
```

Same code with 1 day of difference:

```
$s = 84600; // 23.5 h in seconds
$s += (60*60*24)*37; // add 37 days in seconds
$d = (new \DateTime())->modify("-".$s."seconds");
echo (new \DateTime())->diff($d)->format("%a days %h:%I");
// shows: 37 days 23:30
```

PHP version 5.6.2. Tested on localhost, server and http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ with same result.

Comment: Rather than calculating seconds to days and using modify, why not subtract an interval `$d = (new \DateTime())->sub(new DateInterval('PT'.$s.'S'));`

Comment: But what date did daylight savings change in your timezone?

Comment: Yea, it looks like sub takes into consideration time change, and modify doesn't. So real date is more accurate using sub, thanks. But then problem is the same with diff. Yesterday problem occured with date > 38 days, now it's with date > 46 days - when daylight saving change occured.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if you looking for this kind of work around

```
   <?php
    $s= 84600;
    $ts=  strtotime('38 day 30 second', 0);
    $difference=$ts-$s;
    $days = floor($difference / 86400);
    $hours = floor(($difference - $days * 86400) / 3600);
    $minutes = floor(($difference - $days * 86400 - $hours * 3600) / 60);
    $seconds = floor($difference - $days * 86400 - $hours * 3600 - $minutes * 60);

    echo "{$days} days {$hours} hours {$minutes} minutes {$seconds} seconds";
?>

//Output 37 days 0 hours 30 minutes 30 seconds
```

Comment: It's manual way to calculate it instead of OO, but I will probably use something like this right now as work around, thanks.